# Slow Java Program

Tags: java, methods, execute

i have got a problem, lets say i have got code like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
startMethod1();
startMethod2();
}
```

Now, if startMethod1 method is very big and takes a lot of time to execute it, startMethod2 is started before startMethod1 has been finished.
How to make those methods execute 1 by 1?

Comment: can we have some context here?

Comment: are you starting Threads in startMethod1()? Are you calling startMethod2() from startMethod1()? If not I don't see a possibility why startMethod2() should start before StartMethod1() returns. Java executes the commands in order and will not call startMethod2() from your main method before startMethod1() returns

Comment: what is your evidence that startMethod2() is started before the other method finishes?

Comment: java ain't windows. just because a method is called "start..." doesn't mean it starts a process or something

Comment: do you want them to run in parallel, instead of 1 by 1. because they already are 1 by 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> startMethod2 is started before startMethod1 has been finished.

This will never happen. You can start threads in `startMethod1` which could still be running as `startmethod2` starts. `startMethod2` cannot start before `startMethod1` unless `startMethod1` calls `startMethod2`

If you want to wait until the threads in startmethod1 have finished you have to `Thread.join()` them or use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`

> How to make those methods execute 1 by 1?

Just as you have written the code.

Comment: if i am using threads in startmethod1 and it takes time to execute it, startMethod2 is running in same time as startmethod1

Comment: you left that tiny piece of info out of your question

Comment: startmethod2 cannot start until startmethod1 finishes (even if the threads it started have not)

Comment: ok, thx a lot, and sorry that i forgot writing about threads in the topic

Comment: I have added a comment on how to wait for the Threads you started before continuing.

Answer (score 3):

They already do.  The way you've written it, `startMethod2` will not start until `startMethod1` runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Threads then please change your code-example... but i pretend that you did, because your comment on another question showed that you meant to ;-)

You might take a look at wait() and notify()

Call wait() to tell the current Thread to suspend, and notify() to wake it up again

Comment: This is far too vague to be a useful answer.

Comment: Changed it, now it shouldnt be as vague, i will provide an example in an hour or two when i am out of hurry

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using some kind of message logging API which is buffering, and hence some output is appearing much later than you expect. Possibly not even flushing until the end of the program. Hence you're getting interleaved output which is misleading you.

Comment: and now you've told us about your threads I'll rescind that guess ...